# Why doesn't positive lookahead work as first capture group?

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm using the following regex;

```
((?:_missing_:|_exists_:)[a-z0-9]+)|(([a-z0-9]+)(?=:))
```

To match a lucene query string;

```
_missing_:title age:(>=10 AND < 20) AND age:123 AND _exists_:title123
```

The first non-capture group is not respected and returns `_missing_:title` and not `title`. Using a positive lookahead makes the entire regex fail to match anything.

It should return the following array;

```
['title', 'age', 'age', 'title123']
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your regex like below and then grab the strings you want from group index 1 and 2.

```
(?:_missing_:|_exists_:)([a-z1-9]+)|([a-z1-9]+)(?=:)
```

You don't need to include the non-capturing group `(?:_missing_:|_exists_:)` inside a capturing group. This is the reason for returning `missing:title` instead of `title` . And also Capturing group for `[a-z1-9]+` would be enough.

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/oT4qY8/3)

Comment: Sure, I've tried many variations, this still doesn't return correctly using the match function in JavaScript. Returns [ '_missing_:title', 'age', 'age', '_exists_:ti123tle' ]

Comment: string.match only give the results. You need to push the group 1 and group 2 captures into an array.

Answer (score 0):

What you want isn't a lookahead, it's a lookbehind: `(?<=)`:

```
/(?<=_missing_:|_exists_:)([a-z0-9]+)|([a-z0-9]+)(?=:)/
```

[Test](https://regex101.com/r/esWxv1/1).

Now `([a-z0-9]+)` is matched **only** when there's `_missing_:` or `_exists_:` behind, but those aren't part of the match.

The fist non-capture group was being respected, when you do: `/((?:_missing_:|_exists_:)[a-z0-9]+)/` the first group spans the whole thing `_missing_:title`, the second group is `_missing_:` but that isn't captured, and `title` doesn't belong in any group.

However, even though it isn't captured, it's still matched, similar to `/(_missing_:[a-z0-9]+)/`. What you want is to capture `title`, so you need to put that inside a group `()`: `/((?:_missing_:|_exists_:)([a-z0-9]+))/`. Now you have **three** groups: `_missing_:title`, `_missing_:` (not captured), and `title`.

You could make the outer group non-capture: `/(?:(?:_missing_:|_exists_:)([a-z0-9]+))/`, but there's no need, because you aren't actually using it, so just remove it:

```
/(?:_missing_:|_exists_:)([a-z0-9]+)/
```

Now the first group is `title`. However, it will still be part of the match, which doesn't seem to be what you want.

To remove it from the match, you need a positive lookbehind:

```
/(?<=_missing_:|_exists_:)([a-z0-9]+)/
```

Also, since you are using a positive lookahead in the second part, it isn't necessary to put it inside an outer group, so just:

```
([a-z0-9]+)(?=:)
```